# Exclude some fields from JSON Body in POST request using Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I am using Retrofit2 to send and receive requests to my server.

Here are my API interface and Model class.

1. Interface

   ```
   public interface ApiInterface {

      @POST("/users/")
      Call<User> signUp(@Body User user);

      @POST("/login_url/")
      Call<User> login(@Body User user);
   }
   ```
2. Retrofit client

   ```
   public class RetrofitClient {

      private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

      public static Retrofit getRestClient(String baseUrl) {
          if (retrofit == null) {
              retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                   .build();
          }
          return retrofit;
      }
   }
   ```
3. POJO class

   ```
   public class User {

       @SerializedName("id")
       private Integer id;

       @SerializedName("email")
       @Expose
       private String email;

       @SerializedName("first_name")
       private String firstName;

       @SerializedName("last_name")
       private String lastName;

       @SerializedName("password")
       @Expose
       private String password;
   }
   ```

I have exposed email and password so that in login request these 2 parameters will be added.
But for another request like Sign up, I required a first name and last name also to be sent along with email and password.

Can I use same "User" class for both ? because if I expose the first name and last name then, those fields will be also sent in login request.

Is there any other way or should I make different POJO classes for both request ?

Comment: why not send just the parameters?

Comment: means do I need to prepare JSON object by my own add as parameters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of sending the whole class , you can use **@Field** annotation , so your login callback will be something like this :

```
@FormUrlEncoded    
@POST("/login_url/")
Call<User> login(@field("email")String email,@field("password")String password);
```

**@FormUrlEncoded** denotes that the request body will use form URL encoding. Fields should be declared as parameters and annotated with **@Field**.

Comment: Is this will convert request body into JSON with the fields which are added in request?

Comment: This is too much work if the model that i am working with has a lot of fields to INCLUDE and only a few to EXCLUDE

Comment: @zulkarnainshah at this time you can use **@Body** annotation before adding the model class as a parameter which will be more useful choosing which fields to include/exclude .

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use same `"User"` class for both ?

**Yes** , you can use the same **`Model`** as **`@Body`** for both requests !

Just make sure where you don't need the `required variables` just *omit* them !!

Remove the `@SerializedName` and `@Expose` , these are not required and give the `variable names` according to the **json KEYs**

```
public class User {

   private Integer id;

   private String email;

   private String firstName;

   private String lastName;

   private String password;

}
```

**Edit**

Suppose for example , for one request you need :-

- 4 params you set the model user as

  ```
   new User(id,email,firstname,lastname); // dont init the password attribute
  ```
- 5 params you set all values to the `model` like

  ```
   new User(id,email,firstname,lastname,password);
  ```

Comment: but how can I omit? For example, Login API requires 2 parameters and Sign up API requires 4 parameters of common model class.

Comment: i have updated the answer please check the edit @KhushbuShah